# How can I have a Tabbar view like this in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, tabbar

I want to have a tabbar like this one in flutter. But couldn't find any solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZEc5.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. move the containers in a row

   2. wrap the container in a GestureDetector and in onTap do your navigation

new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.red)
  ),
  child: new Text("Matches"),
),
new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.red)
  ),
  child: new Text("Standings"),
)

Comment: already done that. But I am trying to design the Tabrar like this. The way you are saying, it will work like a button, not like a tabbar

Comment: the link you posted is not a tabbar in the sense of materialdesign nor flutter. you want it like take you have to build from scratch